# why size of array printed as zero in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

what is wrong with this below code ? 
why it is printing size of array as zero?

```
function test() {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    console.log('i ->' + i);
    arr.push[i];
  }
  console.log('\n' + 'array length :' + arr.length);
}
```

--

**Output:**

```
i ->0
i ->1
i ->2
i ->3
i ->4
i ->5
i ->6
i ->7
i ->8
i ->9

array length :0
```

--

it is printing as zero(0)

Comment: Not sure why you're using a subscripting operator there `[]`... try `arr.push(i);`.

Comment: thanks for finding the mistake. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a function.

You need to write `arr.push(i)` and not `arr.push[i]`. What you're doing in the latter is referring to `arr.push` as if it were an array, and then trying to access its `i`th subscript (or assuming that `push` is an object and trying to access a property that has the same value of `i`); it's effectively the same as writing a single line statement like so:

```
someArray[i];
```

Which doesn't really do anything.

**Note:** I have been bitten by this silly bug many times as well when I type too fast. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Because `.push[i]` should be `.push(i)`.

The reason you didn't get an error is that functions are objects in JavaScript, so you can legally get and set properties on functions.

What you were doing was fetching the the `i` property from the `Array.prototype.push` method *(which will be `undefiend`)*.

```
console.log(arr.push[i]); // undefined
```

---

Probably worth noting that [`jsHint`](http://jshint.com) would catch this for you.